# Running powershell script fails on windows server salve

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, windows-server

I have the below code which runs from `Jenkins` on `windows server 2019` slave:

```
$Username = $args[0]
$Password = $args[1]
$Env = $args[2]

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force 
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

echo "********  Start SQL Deploy  ********"

Start-Process -FilePath msbuild  -ArgumentList '"Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj"','/t:deploy', '/p:Configuration=Release', '/p:TargetConnectionString=$Env', '/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True', '/p:TargetDatabase="test_fsdb"','-fl','-flp:logfile=msbuild.log' -wait -LoadUserProfile -credential $cred 

Get-Content msbuild.log


echo "********  End SQL Deploy  ********"
```

The parameters comes form `Jenkinsfile`. I'm using applicative user.
The error is:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The service cannot be started, either because it is 
disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

I was able to run it locally, so I wonder if it's kind of permission issue on the salve...

Comment: Is msbuild in the same Directory?

Comment: `msbuild` path was defined in system variables PATH

Comment: Does it make any difference using the full path instead of relying on the predefined path? Also,  have you checked to see if there's a related service that is disabled like it's mentioning? Worth a look

Comment: @Bhargav Rao can you tell me why answer was deleted?